# Two number fields with isomorphic Galois groups but different Galois closure of their maximal real subfields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

$\newcommand\Q{\mathbb Q}$Suppose $G$ is a transitive finite permutation subgroup of $S_{2n}$ having fixpoint-free involution in and outside its center. Suppose furthermore that I know that there is a (totally) imaginary Galois number field $K$ whose Galois group is isomorphic to $G$. So I also want $[K:\Q]=2n$. My question is the following:

If the complex conjugation is not in the center of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\Q)$ then the maximal real subfield of $K$ is not Galois. But can I find another imaginary Galois number field $L$ with Galois group isomorphic to $G$ such that the complex conjugation is in the center of $G$? Vice versa, if the maximal real subfield of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\Q)$ is Galois, can I find an imaginary number field $L$ with Galois group isomorphic to $G$ such that its maximal real subfield is not Galois?

Comment: What is the smallest group matching your conditions?

Comment: Starting with degree 6 the smallest group with GAP description 6T11 matches this condition: http://galoisdb.math.upb.de/groups/view?deg=6&num=11.

Comment: To be precise: two examples would be the splitting fields of $x^6 + 3x^5 + 9x^4 + 13x^3 + 14x^2 + 8x + 2$ and $x^6 - 2x^5 + 2x^4 - 2x^3 + 2x^2 - x + 1$ respectively having Galois group 6T11 and one has maximal real subfield that is Galois while the other no.